# helm3: semVersion comparison fails in Chart.yaml for version which has "rc"

Tags: kubernetes-helm, semantic-versioning

In `Chart.yaml`

I have `kubeVersion: ">=1.10.1"`

Cluster nodes have below version

`v1.18.0-rc.1`
and helm installation fails with error

```
Error: chart requires kubeVersion: >=1.10.1 which is incompatible with Kubernetes v1.18.0-rc.1
```

I tried changing kubeVersion to `1.10.1-rc.1` but some new error

```
error unmarshaling JSON: while decoding JSON: json: cannot unmarshal bool into Go value of type releaseutil.SimpleHead
```

```
# helm version
version.BuildInfo{Version:"v3.1.2", GitCommit:"d878d4d45863e42fd5cff6743294a11d28a9abce", GitTreeState:"clean", GoVersion:"go1.13.8"}
```

Comment: You specified release version range `>=1.10.1`.  I don't know anything about kubernetes-helm, but I suspect your tool is not configured to allow prereleases.  You'll probably have to manually update to the `-rc.1` version.  Check your documentation for how it handles release vs prereleas versions.

Comment: in my example i have k8s 1.19.0 
but helm complains with Error: chart requires kubeVersion: >=1.19.0-0 which is incompatible with Kubernetes v1.18.0

....which doesnt make sense!  it looks like helm 3.4.1 cannot read the k8s version correctly

Answer (score 7, accepted):

To allow prereleases (such as rc), at least in Helm, the constraints suffix needs to be `-0`. For example, `>=1.20.0-0` will allow versions greater or equal to 1.20.0, including any prereleases.